# Show there exists a positive non-cyclic polynomial $f\left(a,b,c\right)$ so that $f^{2}\left(a,b,c\right)\geq f\left (b,c,a\right)f\left(c,a,b\right)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, substitution

> *My conjecture*. Given three positive numbers $a, b, c$. There exists a positive non-cyclic polynomial $f\left ( a, b, c \right )$ so that
> $$f^{2}\left ( a, b, c \right )\geq f\left ( b, c, a \right )f\left ( c, a, b \right )$$

Is mine right ? I found that there exists a non-cyclic polynomial $f\left ( a, b, c \right )= a- b\neq 0$, which is
$$\left ( a- b \right )^{2}\geq \left ( b- c \right )\left ( c- a \right )$$
because
$$\left ( a- b \right )^{2}- \left ( b- c \right )\left ( c- a \right )= \left ( a+ b- 2c \right )^{2}+ 3\left ( b- c \right )\left ( c- a \right )\geq 0$$

Comment: It's true for all f(a,b,c) are symmetric, and cyclic.

Comment: I think we can only have $f(x,y,z) \geqslant 0$ if $f(x,y,z)$ are symmetric,or cylic.

Comment: @tthnew, ha-ha.

Comment: @DO TOAN NANG Do you want to know, why $(a-b)^2-(b-c)(c-a)\geq0$? If so I am ready to show it.

Comment: No I need to $f$

Comment: @DO TOAN NANG No, it's not so necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there be such $f$.

Thus, we have $$f(a,b,c)^2\geq f(b,c,a)f(c,a,b)$$ and
$$f(b,c,a)^2\geq f(c,a,b)f(a,b,c),$$ which gives
$$f(a,b,c)^2f(b,c,a)^2\geq f(a,b,c)f(b,c,a)f(c,a,b)^2$$ or
$$f(a,b,c)f(b,c,a)\left(f(a,b,c)f(b,c,a)-f(c,a,b)^2\right)\geq0$$ and since $$f(a,b,c)f(b,c,a)>0,$$ we obtain $$f(a,b,c)f(b,c,a)-f(c,a,b)^2\geq0,$$ which gives $$f(a,b,c)f(b,c,a)=f(c,a,b)^2,$$
Similarly $$f(a,b,c)f(c,a,b)=f(b,c,a)^2$$ and
$$f(c,a,b)f(b,c,a)=f(a,b,c)^2.$$
The first and the second from three last equalities give:
$$(f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)(f(b,c,a)-f(c,a,b))=0$$ or $$f(b,c,a)=f(c,a,b)$$ and    similarly we obtain: $$f(a,b,c)=f(b,c,a)=f(c,a,b),$$which gives that $f$ is a cyclic, which is a contradiction.

We see that this reasoning works for any positive function $f$ of three variables.

Comment: Well answered ! Have you considered a career as a bus driver ? Because you just took me to school.

Comment: +1, Nice solution.

Comment: My bad joke 